# How to define URI for types of a certain resource

Tags: rest, restful-architecture, restful-url

Currently, I have an API for showing a list of spots using this route: `GET /spots`

I also have an API which gets the details for a certain spot: `GET /spots/{spot-id}`

Now, I will be making another API, which shows all the categories of the spots. Do you guys know of a proper way to go about with this?

So far I have decided on using `GET /spots/categories` but my manager said it was kind of weird for the spots resource to have categories.

His current suggestions are `GET /spot-categories` and `GET /spotcategories`.

Also, for reference, I have database tables `spot` and `spot_category`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to agree with your manager, your spotcategories look like a different entity altogether, so as a resource it deserves a separate url. That being said, if the goal is to find the categories for a particular spot (as opposed to simply browsing through the different available spotcategories), you should only be able to navigate to them through the spots (presuming your API is on [level 3 of the Richardson Maturity Model](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html#level3)). As in a link from the spots to the categories (or simply embed them, depending on the usage requirements).

So you might end up with something like

```
GET /spots/{spot-id}/categories
```

Comment: Thank you. We decided to go with `GET /spot-categories` in the end. And thanks for the useful reference! I'll try to read through that as well.